# Magento CSV Stock import not making M2EPro update my listings

Tags: magento2, csv, m2epro

I am importing a CSV of stock levels into Magento2 (2.1.6) but that is not triggering any updates to happen to my M2E Pro ebay listings.

It seems that the CSV import doesn't use Magento core, so it doesn't mark a product as updated, so M2E Pro doesn't pick up the fact that the product has had an update, and does nothing.

M2E Pro offers some code snippets that could help with this, but I am at a loss as to how that could be implemented so that it will work when I import a CSV into Magento?

[M2E Pro article](https://docs.m2epro.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19727528#ArticlessuitableforMagentov2.x(fromMagentov1.xBestPractice)-ProgrammaticPossibilitiestoworkwithExtension)

Has anyone done this already, or could help with a solution?